# How to submit a form partially?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a form with many different fields, fields of this form are associated to two tables, 
once the form is submitted what should I do to update the affected table only?

table credential

```
ID
username
password
question
answer
```

table user

```
    ID
    name
    surname
    age
    CredentialID
```

Lets say the user just update his/her name. Once the form is submitted I just need to update the name field of user table and not any field of credential table because its associated fields has not been changed. I know one way is to check the submitted values with the classes is there any other option?
The reason that I do not want to update all the values to increase performance and decrease the database costs. moreover, is any way to do the comparison on client-side? I am using prepareStatement to update the database.

Class

```
  public class User{
      ID
      CredentialID
      name
      surname
      age
      username
      password
      question
      answer
  }
```

form

```
  <s:form action="register" method="POST">
   ... name
   surname
   age
   username
   password
   question
   answer ...
 </s:form>
```

Comment: updating those values which have not been changed wont make a difference as the same values will be overwritten. Is that how you are retrieving the values from the form?

Comment: is there any relation between those tables

Comment: how are you updating DB? are you using hibernate/JPA or anything else?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi, I am using preparestatement

Comment: @PSR, question is updated

Comment: @Aashray, it is not a good idea as it affects database costs and performance

Comment: @DanielMorgan : if the other fields are not changes , then whats the harm in updating those fields , anyways they will be the the same

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid, database and performance costs

Comment: You will not win any of performances  due to the fact of the dirty logic and fetching the database with the right explain plan is the normal way to perform operations on update object state until you not get the snapshot too old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know one way is to check the submitted values with the classes is there any other option?

For me that seems like you know you can check this on server side by comparing all new variables of your class with the old variables, however you would like to have a faster and less resource intensive way.

So, my basic idea how to achieve this is that the client (browser) needs to check if a value of a "group" (credential or user) has changed and submit this information to the server. I am not sure about the HTML markup when using Struts, but basically it looks like this:

```
<form>
   <!-- credential fields -->
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username" onchange="credentialChanged()"/>
   <input type="text" name="question" id="question" onchange="credentialChanged()" />
   ...
   <!-- indicates the server if credential fields have changed -->
   <input type="hidden" name="credential-changed" 
          id="credential-changed" value="false" />

   <!-- uer fields -->
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onchange="userChanged()"/>
   <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" onchange="userChanged()"/>
   ...
   <!-- indicates the server if user fields have changed -->
   <input type="hidden" name="user-changed" 
          id="user-changed" value="false" />
</form>
```

Then you use the javascript functions `credentialChanged()` and `userChanged()` to update the hidden fields:

```
function credentialChanged(){
  document.getElementById("credential-changed").value = "true";
}

function userChanged(){
  document.getElementById("user-changed").value = "true";
}
```

On server side, you can get the values of the hidden fields and know if the values have changed.

*Note*: If the user changed the of a field for example from "UserXYZ" to "UserABC" and then changed it back to "UserXYZ", the value of the appropriate hidden field will be set to true. You will have to add additional Javascript to compare old and new values on client side, but the idea should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have following choices:

1. Maintain a hidden field that contain the same value that a text field has and when the form is submitted compare the text box value with hidden value and accordingly update the table i.e if entered username is not matching with hidden username value, change that credential table only.
2. If it is a form like updating user information then better put each individual fields set in separate form.

Comment: if I go for second option then I would have a submit button for each table right ? then how about if I had 10 tables?

Comment: then I think first options should work fine as before submitting form it will make sure which table it is supposed to talk.

Comment: I suppose the first method is not a good idea as well as it needs a long time of comparison and still affects the performance, I suppose something should be done on client side not the server side.

Comment: try something like:  `<form onSubmit="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" name="username" onChange="form1FieldChaged()" />
    <input type="text" name="password" onChange="form1FieldChaged()" />

    <input type="text" name="surname" onChange="form2FieldChaged()" />
    <input type="text" name="ID" onChange="form2FieldChaged()" />
    </form  >


function form1FieldChaged(){ form1Changed = true;}
function form2FieldChaged(){ form2Changed = true;}

function submit-form(){
 if(form1Changed ==true){update table1}
 else  if(form2Changed ==true){update table2}
}`